# I have retrieved the height of a dynamic table now I need to put that height into another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used this code to get the height of a dynamic table

```
var table = document.getElementById("test");
document.write(table.offsetHeight);
```

But now I need to use that value to set the height of a div beside that table. I don't know how to do this. I was hoping it could be done easily through the inline style of the div but I couldn't do it.

Thanks

Comment: This code actually does not give you the table height

Comment: `div_element.offsetHeight = table.offsetHeight` should work.

Comment: Not quite was I was asking but ok.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know how to get the table's `offsetHeight`, you can set it to the div by the DOM style property:

```
var table = document.getElementById("test");
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = table.offsetHeight + "px";
```

Comment: I tried and it did work: var table = document.getElementById("table");
document.getElementById("testing").style.height = table.offsetHeight + "px";.     Not sure if I placing the code in the correct area of the page.

Comment: I meant to say didn't work.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/6bEjq/

Comment: Whats the reason for the button? I need it to do this when the page loads.

Comment: It was just an example... Here is it without the button: http://jsfiddle.net/6bEjq/1/

Comment: Good looking. That worked.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

you can do

`var height=$('table').height()` to get the height.

For specific div

```
$('div').height(height)
```

rather than writing table you can specify its id also. Same with div. You can specify the id of div to change the height of particular div

Comment: What if he is not using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do this using jquery when the page loads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; float: left;">
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="adjDiv" style="float:left; border: 1px solid red;">
        Div next to the table
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Set height using the id of my div and the height of your table
            $('#adjDiv').height($('#table').height());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```